# Writing Jackson annotation that accepts both string and list of strings

Tags: java, annotations, jax-rs

I am developing a JAX-RS program where one of the parameters is as follows.

```
@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
private String[] name;
```

It accepts both string and array of string. Both of them are converted to Array finally. 
Is there any such annotation which can accept both string and array of string and do not change it to any other type as I want my program to accept  "name" parameter as both string and array of string and retaining their data type?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this wouldn't be possible, because there is not common ancestor type of `String` and `String[]`, (other than Object, which would make it completely useless). However, if you really want to do this, you can make a getter method on the pojo that would return one or the other:

```
public Object getStringOrArrayName() {
    return (name.length == 1) ? name[0] : name;
}
```